# MediaPlayer within TextureView not working as intended

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, android-textureview

I've put in a MediaPlayer within a TextureView, which itself is located inside a ListView.

Yesterday, the MediaPlayer worked as intended with a test .mp4 clip.
Today, the MediaPlayer tries doing some kind of FFmpeg Extractor, for which i've been unable to find any kind of information about.

This is the stack trace:

```
03-14 13:43:00.076 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: SniffFFMPEG
03-14 13:43:00.076 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.077 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android source begin open
03-14 13:43:00.077 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android open, url: android-source:0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.077 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: ffmpeg open android data source success, source ptr: 0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.077 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android source open success
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'android-source:0xafcff040':
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:   Metadata:
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     major_brand     : qt  
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     minor_version   : 0
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     compatible_brands: qt  
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     creation_time   : 2016-03-13 19:24:58
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:   Duration: 00:00:10.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11209 kb/s
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 86 kb/s (default)
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2016-03-13 19:24:58
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11113 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2016-03-13 19:24:58
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       encoder         : H.264
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 1 kb/s (default)
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2016-03-13 19:24:58
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2016-03-13 19:24:58
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtrator, url: android-source:0xafcff040, format_name: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, format_long_name: QuickTime / MOV
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: list the formats suppoted by ffmpeg: 
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: ========================================
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[00]: mpeg
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[01]: mpegts
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[02]: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[03]: matroska,webm
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[04]: asf
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[05]: rm
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[06]: flv
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[07]: swf
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[08]: avi
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[09]: ape
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[10]: dts
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[11]: flac
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[12]: ac3
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[13]: wav
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[14]: ogg
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[15]: vc1
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: format_names[16]: hevc
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: ========================================
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: major_brand tag is:qt  
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: [mp4]format is mov, confidence should be larger than mpeg4
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android source close
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: sniff through BetterSniffFFMPEG success
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? D/FFmpegExtractor: ffmpeg detected media content as 'video/mp4' with confidence 0.41
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? I/MediaExtractor: Use extended extractor for the special mime(video/mp4) or codec
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::FFmpegExtractor
03-14 13:43:00.149 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: mFilename: android-source:0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.150 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android source begin open
03-14 13:43:00.150 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android open, url: android-source:0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.150 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: ffmpeg open android data source success, source ptr: 0xafcff040
03-14 13:43:00.150 477-16532/? D/FFMPEG: android source open success
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: file startTime: 0
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: the duration is 00:00:10.87
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: stream_index: 0
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: support the codec(aac)
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: Tag mp4a/0x6134706d with codec(aac)
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: audio stream extradata(2):
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/codec_utils: AAC
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/codec_utils: aac profile: 1, sf_index: 4, channel: 1
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: bit_rate: 86249, sample_rate: 44100, channels: 1, bits_per_coded_sample: 16, block_align:0
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: the time is 00:00:10.93
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: audio startTime:0
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: create a audio track
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: stream_index: 1
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: support the codec(h264)
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: Tag avc1/0x31637661 with codec(h264)
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: video stream extradata:
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/codec_utils: AVC
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: width: 1920, height: 1080, bit_rate: 11113682
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? I/FFmpegExtractor: the time is 00:00:10.87
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: video startTime:0
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: create a video track
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: the stream is AVC, the length of a NAL unit: 4
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: Starting reader thread
03-14 13:43:00.230 477-16532/? D/FFmpegExtractor: Reader thread started
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: mProbePkts: 0, mEOF: 0, pb->error(if has): 0, mDefersToCreateVideoTrack: 0, mDefersToCreateAudioTrack: 0
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? D/FFmpegExtractor: supported mime: video/mp4
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::getMetaData
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16537/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor enter thread(readerEntry)
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::getTrack[0]
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::getTrackMetaData[0]
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::getTrack[1]
03-14 13:43:00.231 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::getTrackMetaData[1]
03-14 13:43:00.232 10973-10973/com.hobbyte.touringandroid E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
```

Upon trying to play the video file, I get this log:

```
03-14 13:52:06.133 743-821/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-477/? D/NuPlayerDriver: start(0xb0f05040)
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-16531/? I/GenericSource: start
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-16531/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::Track::start audio
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-16531/? V/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtractor::Track::start video
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: read audio flush pkt
03-14 13:52:06.133 477-16532/? V/FFmpegExtractor: read video flush pkt
03-14 13:52:06.139 477-24743/? D/SoftFFmpegAudio: SoftFFmpegAudio component: OMX.ffmpeg.aac.decoder mMode: 1
03-14 13:52:06.141 477-24743/? V/SoftFFmpegAudio: get pcm params, nChannels:4294967295, nSamplingRate:4294967295
03-14 13:52:06.141 477-24743/? V/SoftFFmpegAudio: set OMX_IndexParamAudioPcm, nChannels:1, nSampleRate:44100, nBitsPerSample:16
03-14 13:52:06.141 477-24743/? V/SoftFFmpegAudio: set OMX_IndexParamAudioAac, nChannels:1, nSampleRate:44100
03-14 13:52:06.141 477-24743/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setParameter(1866465283) ERROR: 0x8000101a
03-14 13:52:06.141 477-24743/? V/SoftFFmpegAudio: get pcm params, nChannels:1, nSamplingRate:44100
03-14 13:52:06.147 477-24744/? E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
03-14 13:52:06.147 477-24744/? E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
03-14 13:52:06.149 477-24745/? I/SoftFFmpegAudio: got extradata, ignore: 0, size: 2
03-14 13:52:06.150 477-24745/? I/SoftFFmpegAudio: extradata is ready, size: 2
03-14 13:52:06.150 477-24745/? D/SoftFFmpegAudio: begin to open ffmpeg audio decoder(aac), mCtx sample_rate: 44100, channels: 1, , sample_fmt: (null)
03-14 13:52:06.154 477-24745/? D/SoftFFmpegAudio: open ffmpeg audio decoder(aac) success, mCtx sample_rate: 44100, channels: 1, sample_fmt: fltp
03-14 13:52:06.154 477-24745/? I/SoftFFmpegAudio: Create sample rate converter for conversion of 44100 Hz fltp 1 channels(mono) to 44100 Hz s16 1 channels(mono)!
03-14 13:52:06.154 477-24743/? V/SoftFFmpegAudio: get pcm params, nChannels:1, nSamplingRate:44100
03-14 13:52:06.155 477-24739/? D/AudioSink: bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
03-14 13:52:06.162 477-24747/? E/SoftAVC: Decoder failed: -2
03-14 13:52:06.162 477-24744/? E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
03-14 13:52:06.162 477-24744/? E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
03-14 13:52:06.163 477-24741/? E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
03-14 13:52:06.167 477-24740/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: Failed to queue input buffer for OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
03-14 13:52:06.167 477-16531/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
03-14 13:52:06.168 10973-11040/com.hobbyte.touringandroid E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-14 13:52:06.168 10973-10973/com.hobbyte.touringandroid E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
03-14 13:52:06.168 477-24740/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: failed to flush OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
03-14 13:52:06.168 477-16531/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
03-14 13:52:06.169 10973-10989/com.hobbyte.touringandroid E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-14 13:52:06.170 10973-10973/com.hobbyte.touringandroid E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
```

For reference, here is my class file:

```
    package com.hobbyte.touringandroid.ui.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.FrameworkSampleSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.TrackRenderer;
import com.hobbyte.touringandroid.App;
import com.hobbyte.touringandroid.tourdata.ListViewItem;
import com.hobbyte.touringandroid.internet.LoadImageFromURL;
import com.hobbyte.touringandroid.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author Nikita
 */
public class PoiContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {
    private static final String TAG = "PoiContentAdapter";

    public static final int HEADER = 0;
    public static final int BODY = 1;
    public static final int IMAGE = 2;
    public static final int VIDEO = 3;

    private static Pattern namePattern;
    private static final String FILE_NAME_PATTERN = "https?:\\/\\/[-\\w\\.\\/]*\\/(.+\\.(jpe?g|png|mp4))";

    private ListViewItem[] items;

    private String keyID;

    private TextureView textureView;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private AudioManager audio;

    private ImageButton play;
    private ImageButton replay;
    private ImageButton mute;
    private ImageButton max;
    private SeekBar volume;

    private String filePath;

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items[position].getType();
    }

    public PoiContentAdapter(Context context, ListViewItem[] content, String keyID) {
        super(context, 0, content);
        this.keyID = keyID;
        items = content;
        namePattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_NAME_PATTERN);
    }

    /**
     * Inflates a certain view depending on the type of ListViewItem (Normal text or Image URL)
     * @param position Position of item in the ItemList
     * @param view View
     * @param parent ParentView
     * @return the view in question
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListViewItem listViewItem = items[position];
        int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(position);
        String filename = null;

        TextView contentView;

        if (listViewItem.getUrl() != null) {
            Matcher m = namePattern.matcher(listViewItem.getUrl());
            if (m.matches()) {
                filename = m.group(1);
            }
        }

        if (view == null) {
            if (listViewItemType == IMAGE) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poi_image, parent, false);
            } else if(listViewItemType == VIDEO) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poi_video, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poi_content, parent, false);
            }
        }

        switch (listViewItemType) {
            case IMAGE:
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentImageView);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentImageDesc);
                textView.setText(listViewItem.getText());

                if (filename != null) {
                    new LoadImageFromURL(imageView, App.context).execute(filename, keyID); //Load image in a separate thread
                }
                return view;

            case VIDEO:
                filePath = getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + String.format("%s/video/%s", keyID, filename);
                File file = new File(filePath);
                if(!file.exists()) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poi_content, parent, false);
                    contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentTextView);
                    contentView.setText("This contains a video." + "\n" + "Download this tour with Media to see this Video!" + "\n");
                    contentView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    textureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentVideoView);

                    DisplayMetrics metrics = App.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                    int height = metrics.heightPixels / 2;
                    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                    textureView.setMinimumHeight(height);
                    textureView.setMinimumWidth(width);

                    play = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                    replay = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.replayButtoon);
                    mute = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
                    max = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.maxVolButton);
                    volume = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.volumeControl);
                    audio = (AudioManager) App.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(videoListener);
                    TextView videoDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentVideoDesc);
                    videoDesc.setText(listViewItem.getText());
                }
                return view;
            case HEADER:
                // TODO
                if(view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentTextView) == null) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poi_content, parent, false);
                }
                contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentTextView);
                contentView.setText(listViewItem.getText() + "\n");
                if(listViewItem.getText().length() == 0) {
                    return new View(getContext());
                }
                return view;
            case BODY:
                // TODO
                contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentTextView);
                contentView.setText(listViewItem.getText() + "\n");
                return view;
            default:
                contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiContentTextView);
                contentView.setText("Something went wrong\n");
                return view;
        }
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener videoListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface s = new Surface(surface);
            try {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setDataSource(filePath);
                player.setSurface(s);
                player.prepareAsync();
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
                player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                });
                player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                });
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.pause();
                                    play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_white_36dp);
                                } else {
                                    mp.start();
                                    play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_pause_white_36dp);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                                    play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_white_36dp);
                                    mp.pause();
                                    mp.seekTo(0);
                                } else {
                                    play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_white_36dp);
                                    mp.seekTo(0);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mp.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                                volume.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        });
                        max.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                                volume.setProgress(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                            }
                        });

                        int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        int currVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        volume.setMax(maxVolume);
                        volume.setProgress(currVolume);
                        volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                                audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                player.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                });
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            if (player != null) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
                player = null;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
}
```

I really do not understand in the slightest what is causing all these errors, and why the video file won't play?
If anyone is able to help I will highly highly appreciate it!

I am using Genymotion Emulator - Google Nexus 4 - API 21

Thank you very much!

Comment: It sometimes now loads without doing that whole FFmpeg Extraction, but upon playing (Still waits for onPrepared) it gives the error code:

E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)

Comment: From the logs it looks like ffmpeg is used by the emulator for demuxing and AAC decoding. The serious complaints seem more to do with OMX.google.h264.decoder (the software AVC video decoder). Have you tried this on a physical device, or just an emulator?

Comment: Seemed to be a problem with the Emulator. I checked on a standard Android phone and worked fine, reset the emulator and created a new one, it then worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the Emulator. Tested on an Android Phone and worked fine, reset the Genymotion Emulator and created a new one and it proceeded to function as normal.